# Selecting a routing model and storing route data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to do something like a comprehensive system of automation activities. The program is supposed to have a lot of modules. I plan to organize them according to the windows principle. If necessary, you can open a new module, then you can either close it, or open a new one without closing it, to return later.

For example. I open the module of the list of available digital documents. I select the desired one, click on edit, the editing form is launched. I open any information guide, look the necessary data, I come back to the form. This is all done by analogy to the windows taskbar.

I'm working out the architecture. We load modules through vue-router. You can store inactive module data using keep-alive, but there are limited management options. You can only specify how many caches to keep, but there is no way to clear certain ones, and all the data will be kept. I, on the other hand, wanted to be able to choose how much data to keep and what data is not needed as it becomes obsolete. I am worried about the big application not slowing down and not freezing on low-powered computers. On the one hand simple implementation, on the other hand more efficient use of resources.

In addition to the keep-alive choice or storing state data in separate structures, you can think of other options. For example, opening modules in separate tabs, then the data management is transferred to the browser. Or you can implement the option of opening modules in a dynamically added array of components "component", temporarily hide unused ones using v-show directive. You can load modules into dialog boxes. You can think of other options. If you choose one of them, you will have to bear the burden of its corresponding disadvantages.

Writing test versions of each option and then running evaluation tests is too time consuming a task. So I hope for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I think having dialogs or any other component (tabs, etc) would simply work when using `v-if` and `v-show`. You can use v-show for the ones you want to keep in DOM and v-if for the ones you want to destroy after the user is closing them.

See the documentation about the difference between `v-if` and `v-show` [here](https://here:https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show).

Comment: I roughly know how to implement each of the options. I'm more interested in your opinion, which of the options is the best combination of simplicity and efficiency.